# Firebase not showing upload button to upload .p12 certificate

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I am trying to upload the .p12 certificate so that I can enable push notifications on my ionic 2 project. I have the certificate ready but I can't find the upload button.[image]

where can I find the upload button ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out I needed to be made an owner of the project by the account administrator, and not just an editor. If you are part of a team, make sure you have the right privileges.